# Sphinx: Linking a Lexer with a style sheet using pygments

Tags: python, python-sphinx, lexer, pygments

Good evening,

Lets say I am using the built java lexer in pygments to highlight the syntax of a code block in a sphinx document. How do I change the style sheet that the java lexer is associated with. (i.e. I want to change the color of the words that are being highlighted).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just point [pygments_style](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-pygments_style) setting to your custom pygments style class. Also see [how to](http://pygments.org/docs/styles/) write a custom pygments style class.

Should work in theory - haven't tried it by myself though.

Hope that helps.